# javascript: Problem with dynamically adding xsl-stylesheet to XML Data

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, firefox-addon

I'm trying to write my first Firefox-Extension. The extension is supposed to display FOAF-Files in a nice way using XSLT. Right now I just want to add the XSL Stylesheet to the rdf file when I press a button. The function is called but the presentation of the rdf-file does not change.

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayMyResult()
{
    alert("test")
    xml=loadXMLDoc("http://www.example.com/me.rdf");
    xsl=loadXMLDoc("http://www.example.com/test.xsl");
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
            ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
            content.document.location.replace(ex)
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
    {
            xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
            resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
            content.document.location.replace(ex)
    }
}
```

The first function loadXMLDoc is copied from another post here, and should probably work. The Probem is in the displayMyResult Method. The test alert confirms, that the function is called but the me.rdf file is not displayed any different.

I believe that the line content.document.location.replace(ex) is wrong but have not found anything on the web that would explain to me what to use instead.

Can anybody tell me how to load the XLST stylesheet to present the RDF File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does your code intended for a Mozilla extension do checks for IE objects like "ActiveXObject"?
Anyway, your code does not make much sense, your Mozilla branch never assigns to the variable named `ex`, yet you then call `replace(ex)`.
Some more meaningful code would be

```
var resultFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, content.document);
content.document.replaceChild(resultFragment, content.document.documentElement);
```

But I am not sure that will work in general, in particular if content.document is of a different type than the result document of the XSLT (i.e. one being an HTML document, the other being an SVG document).